# Android Base64 URL Encoding

Tags: java, android, java-8, base64, urlencode

I'am trying to send a picture to the server (store it in a folder).

I have a picture as a `byte[]` type, I want to use `import java.util.Base64;`

because i can take advantage of `static Base64.Encoder getUrlEncoder()` which is a

safe conversion because it returns a `Base64.Encoder` that encodes using the `URL`

and Filename safe type base64 encoding scheme.

However when i try to `import java.util.Base64;` Base 64 is always flashing red

with an error Cannot Resolve Symbol Base64.

**please note that my android project is indexing to a 1.8.0 jdk**

Can you please help ?

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `android.util.Base64`?

Comment: is it safe to use it for url encoding ? if yes can you give an example ? thank you.

Comment: Rather than just ask, I suggest you do research. Have a look at the Javadoc for starters...

Comment: but it's not my main question, do you have a solution for the main problem ?

Comment: `Android Base64 URL Encoding`. A bad idea to base64 encode an image. Your data bytes will  be 30% more. If it is your own server then change it to accept the bytearray.

Comment: Android (API 25) doesn't yet have java.util.Base64.

Comment: thank you @StefanZobel for the information. greenapps i'am only prompt to send a string type from my http request.

Comment: Glad to help. You must not assume that Android 7.x has all the Java 8 functionality. For example, there is currently no `java.time` package. Always refer to the  [Android API doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: "do you have a solution for the main problem" - your main question is performing base64 encoding, is it not? Using `android.util.Base64` *is* a solution for that problem.

Comment: tried to use `android.util.Base64` especially `Base64.encodeToString(picture_byte, Base64.DEFAULT);` unfortunately i didn't receive a server response and afterwards the application crashed.